# How to use theforeman/foreman to bootstrap?

Tags: puppet, foreman

I've used the Foreman installer in the past to get a server up and running, but I'm now trying to do the same thing as a bootstrap I can reliably repeat. There's a PuppetForge module, `theforeman/foreman`, but it has almost no documentation aside from "read the source".

Is there a resource listing the minimum setup I can use in a .pp file to get the Foreman installed using this?

Comment: As lot of Github open source stuff, you have to discuss with the author. Sorry but actually, the answer is no.

Comment: The Foreman installer is just a wrapper to puppet-foreman and https://github.com/theforeman?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=puppet-foreman , https://github.com/theforeman/puppet-foreman/ what exactly do you want to accomplish? I would recommend you to ask on the mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/foreman-users/) or #theforeman on Freenode IRC.